# I have implemented xdomain scripts on both client and server end, but in IE9 keep getting a 'Timeout waiting on iframe socket' warning

Tags: javascript, sockets, iframe, internet-explorer-9, xdomainrequest

On the client, I have:

```
<script src="js/plugins/xdomain.min.js" slave="https://api/proxy.html"></script>
```

Then on the server, I have a proxy.html with:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<script src="js/xdomain.min.js"></script>
<script>
  xdomain.masters({
    "https://*.localhost" : '/.*/',
    "https://*.host.net" : '/.*/'
  });
</script>
```

In dev tools on IE9, I have xdomain logging:

```
 'proxying request to slave:'
 'new socket:'
 'Timeout waiting on iframe socket'
```

I'm not seeing any data being passed to the client - i.e -my models within my controllers are empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should open up your proxy.html in a browser and see if it is sending a 'X-Frame-Options' header, if it is, this will be preventing IE9 from opening up the page in an iFrame. You will have to turn off the 'X-Frame-Options' header for proxy.html, and then it should work.

Comment: Adding to this, you can set X-Frame-Options to ALLOW-FROM http://yourdomain.com to allow this to work with your particular site.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this was happening because the xdomain.js file wasn't accessible (403) from the proxy.html file.